# Can I Create A Local Area Network Using TOR?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

I've been using tor for quite a while now and I want to create a private ip network/lan but want it to be secure. I will try to explain this as best as I can.

Basically what I want to do is build a lan using tor. I want to be able to use a tool like scallion (https://github.com/lachesis/scallion) and have my users or me to be able to create a .onion and setup a local web server and have it point to the .onion they've just created (Not going through the internet). I've tried everything I could, I've tried options in the torrc like hiddenserviceport 8080 10.0.0.5:8080 and hiddenservicedir C:/Users//tor_hidden_service, I've tried google and the closest results i'm getting to what I want to do is "How can I share my tor with lan devices". Does tor require internet to work? Can I setup a relay with a lan ip address and configure that in tor browser somehow? Sorry if it is a lot to ask but I've been trying this for days and can't get it to work. ANY HELP is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible fixes

1. Try a standard torrc port ie. `10.0.0.8:90xx` not :8xxx-8080's
2. C:\Users... is not an admin or root acount.
3. I don't do Windoz especially web servers hard to configure.
4. I recommend that you partition your server's HDD and install a linux distro on it.
5. Question: how have you configured your exit-node?

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tor+exit+node+configuration&t=ftas&ia=images***

### :neckbeard:

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the reply, I will note down what you've suggested and create an ubuntu server linux distro, and I haven't setup an exit node yet. But what I did was edited the torrc file and made a bridge.

Comment: U might want to check out this [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tor#Running_a_Tor_exit_node)

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible! You need to rise up your own Directories services and after that you will use a `TransPort` proxying to merge the network subspace. There are some advanced scenarios like using OpenVPN to gain the full network stack like UDP